# how to check time comparsion in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I want to check current time is between given two times or not, using mysql query like below,

```
id start_time end_time
1  08:00 PM   08:00 AM

select *,if((serverTime >= startTime and serverTime <= endTime),'MetTheTime','DintMetTheTime') as Status  from( select STR_TO_DATE(concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_time, ' ', 1),':00 ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_time, ' ', -1)),'%l:%i:%S %p') as startTime,STR_TO_DATE(concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(end_time, ' ', 1),':00 ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(end_time, ' ', -1)),'%l:%i:%S %p') as endTime,time(now()) as serverTime from( select start_time,end_time from table  where id=1) a) b;
```

when i execute the query output is :

```
startTime  endTime   serverTime  Status
20:00:00   08:00:00  03:47:57    DintMetTheTime
```

but expected output is :

```
startTime  endTime   serverTime  Status
20:00:00   08:00:00  03:47:57    MetTheTime
```

where am i doing wrong?

Based on answer posts. I made type into `Time`

```
select *,if((serverTime >= startTime and serverTime <= endTime),'MetTheTime','DintMetTheTime') as Status  from( select start_time as startTime, end_time as endTime,time(now()) as serverTime from( select start_time,end_time from table  where id=1) a) b;
```

But Still that condition not works?

Comment: make sure your field type is `time` in the table

Comment: but i am not supposed to keep field type is time. It must be String.

Comment: thn try using  `STR_TO_DATE(startTime  , "%h:%i:%s")` instead of `startTime`  in your query and same with others then compare the time

Comment: I tried it. but still same result.

Comment: @PunitGajjar even i tried in type as time. but still that condition not works.

Comment: @PunitGajjar check my updated question.

Comment: check first   that  are you getting a perfect result from query if you dont include this condition : `if((serverTime >= startTime and serverTime <= endTime),'MetTheTime','DintMetTheTime') as Status`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have insufficient logic to account for overnights. In your example `serverTime >= startTime`, as you can see `'03:47:57' >= '20:00:00'` is false, not true.

You'll need to work out some special-purpose logic for use in the case where your end time value is smaller than your start time value; that indicates an overnight time interval.

Answer (score -1):

very simple solution just change your table's column data type as `datetime` instead `time` and store date as well as time and now it should calculate properly

Comment: I should store the time as 08:00 PM not 08:00:00.

Comment: not compulsory as you can convert the string to time-stamp.